# Is there any function so that i can calculate the length of each users skill's at once and then find which user have the maximum skills?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, methods

Find the person who has many skills in the users' object.

```
const users = {
  Alex: {
    email: 'alex@alex.com',
    skills: ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript'],
    age: 20,
    isLoggedIn: false,
    points: 30
  },
  Asab: {
    email: 'asab@asab.com',
    skills: ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript', 'Redux', 'MongoDB', 'Express', 'React', 'Node'],
    age: 25,
    isLoggedIn: false,
    points: 50
  },
  Brook: {
    email: 'daniel@daniel.com',
    skills: ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript', 'React', 'Redux'],
    age: 30,
    isLoggedIn: true,
    points: 50
  },
  Daniel: {
    email: 'daniel@alex.com',
    skills: ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript', 'Python'],
    age: 20,
    isLoggedIn: false,
    points: 40
  },
}
```

Is there any function so that I can calculate the length of each users skill's at once and then find which user have the maximum skills?

Comment: You can just sort the `Object.entries` by skills.length and pop the highest one. `const result = Object.entries(users).sort((a, b) => a[1].skills.length - b[1].skills.length).pop()` (returns a tuple of `[name, values]`)

Comment: Just a side note. The answers would be much simpler if your data was in the form of "array of objects" instead of "object with objects". (See that the answers below use Object.entries to convert to some array because of that). For example `const users = [{name:Alex, email:'alex@alex.com',...},{...},{...}]`. This would allow for duplicate names, as well as `map`, `Math.max`, `push`,`sort` and other useful array methods for your data handling. Array (generally) is a more appropriate structure for grouping "similar" things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like this

```js
const userWithMaxSkills = users => Object.entries(users)
.reduce((res, [username, data]) => {
    if(data.skills.length > res.maxSkills){
      return {
        maxSkills: data.skills.length,
        user: {
          [username]: data
        }
      }
    }
    return res
}, 
 { 
  maxSkills: -1,
  user: undefined
 }
).user

const users = {
  Alex: {
    email: 'alex@alex.com',
    skills: ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript'],
    age: 20,
    isLoggedIn: false,
    points: 30
  },
  Asab: {
    email: 'asab@asab.com',
    skills: ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript', 'Redux', 'MongoDB', 'Express', 'React', 'Node'],
    age: 25,
    isLoggedIn: false,
    points: 50
  },
  Brook: {
    email: 'daniel@daniel.com',
    skills: ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript', 'React', 'Redux'],
    age: 30,
    isLoggedIn: true,
    points: 50
  },
  Daniel: {
    email: 'daniel@alex.com',
    skills: ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript', 'Python'],
    age: 20,
    isLoggedIn: false,
    points: 40
  },
}

console.log(userWithMaxSkills(users))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) the [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) by `skills.length` and retrieve the first element. Here turning the result back into an object with [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries).

```js
const users = { Alex: { email: 'alex@alex.com', skills: ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript'], age: 20, isLoggedIn: false, points: 30 }, Asab: { email: 'asab@asab.com', skills: ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript', 'Redux', 'MongoDB', 'Express', 'React', 'Node'], age: 25, isLoggedIn: false, points: 50 }, Brook: { email: 'daniel@daniel.com', skills: ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript', 'React', 'Redux'], age: 30, isLoggedIn: true, points: 50 }, Daniel: { email: 'daniel@alex.com', skills: ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript', 'Python'], age: 20, isLoggedIn: false, points: 40 }, };

const result = Object.fromEntries([
  Object.entries(users).sort((a, b) => b[1].skills.length - a[1].skills.length)[0]
]);

console.log(result);
```

But I completely agree with @DimVai s comment – an array is definitely a more appropriate choice for data of this type, and also simplifies retrieving your desired result.

```js
const users = [{ name: 'Alex', email: 'alex@alex.com', skills: ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript'], age: 20, isLoggedIn: false, points: 30 }, { name: 'Asab', email: 'asab@asab.com', skills: ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript', 'Redux', 'MongoDB', 'Express', 'React', 'Node'], age: 25, isLoggedIn: false, points: 50 }, { name: 'Brook', email: 'daniel@daniel.com', skills: ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript', 'React', 'Redux'], age: 30, isLoggedIn: true, points: 50 }, { name: 'Daniel', email: 'daniel@alex.com', skills: ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript', 'Python'], age: 20, isLoggedIn: false, points: 40 },];

const [result] = users.sort((a, b) => b.skills.length - a.skills.length);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const users = {
  Alex: {
    email: 'alex@alex.com',
    skills: ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript'],
    age: 20,
    isLoggedIn: false,
    points: 30
  },
  Asab: {
    email: 'asab@asab.com',
    skills: ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript', 'Redux', 'MongoDB', 'Express', 'React', 'Node'],
    age: 25,
    isLoggedIn: false,
    points: 50
  },
  Brook: {
    email: 'daniel@daniel.com',
    skills: ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript', 'React', 'Redux'],
    age: 30,
    isLoggedIn: true,
    points: 50
  },
  Daniel: {
    email: 'daniel@alex.com',
    skills: ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript', 'Python'],
    age: 20,
    isLoggedIn: false,
    points: 40
  },
}

let maxSkills=Object.entries(users)[0][1].skills.length
let personWhoHasMostSkills=Object.entries(users)[0][0]
for(let i=0;i<Object.keys(users).length;i++)
{
    if(Object.entries(users)[i][1].skills.length>maxSkills)
    {
        maxSkills=Object.entries(users)[i][1].skills.length
        personWhoHasMostSkills=Object.entries(users)[i][0]
    }
}
console.log(`The person with the most skills: ${personWhoHasMostSkills} and number of skills: ${maxSkills}`)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).